Ubuntu 22.04.2 How to fix Malformed entry 1 in source list(Component)
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Inside  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros2.org/ros2/ubuntu  main


Add the word jammy before main so the last part looks like this
http://packages.ros2.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy main

Source: https://docs.ros.org/en/dashing/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Binary.html#add-the-ros-2-apt-repository
